# How create directory on my local machine

Tags: c#

I would love to ask ,what is wrong with th following code ,because i've been trying to             create a folder on my local machine but it does not work according to my expectactions.
It gives me a Error saying :

> Access to the path 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot//PrintLabels/' is denied

Code:

```
Directory.CreateDirectory(appPath + "//PrintLabels/");
```

Comment: What is appPath ? Is this application running on a Web server or a Winforms application ? Is the user running  the application granted to write in this directory (check ACLs) ?

Comment: this is not a code problem - it is just saying that the user running this code does not have sufficient permissions (security) to create a directory at that location...

Comment: Please use `Path.Combine` instead of manually adding strings and random numbers of slashes.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8525389/1719369. Similar issue.

Comment: @Yahia thank you very much ,i solved the problem i ddnt have full control on wwwwroot folder ,and then i went to change securities changed it to full control now its working perfectly there was nothing wrong with my code.thnks again.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Windows Vista or above, then first close Visual Studio, then right-click its icon and select run as administrator option. Then when you execute the code, it should stop giving access denied exception.

Comment: yes im running it as a administrator but still its not coming right

Answer (score 1):

The specified path must be on same machine or can also refer to a relative path or a Universal Naming Convention (UNC) path for a server and share name.

It must be

```
 string path = @"\\172.16.136.35\\SharedFolder1\\";
```

The IP Address replaces the use of the computer name. You must not use them both.

```
string path  = @"\\ipaddress\comp_name\shared_folder\new_folder";
```

Should be:

```
string path  = @"\\ipaddress\shared_folder\new_folder";
```

Note that the IP Adress is the one of the computer where the shared folder is, not the one from which you send your request.

Comment: can i use the following code ,inorder for me to create a folder using my ipAddress ?   Directory.CreateDirectory(appPath + "//PrintLabels/");
                StreamWriter w;
                w = File.CreateText(appPath + "//PrintLabels/" + "/Testfile.txt");
                w.WriteLine(fileContents.ToString());
                w.Flush();
                w.Close();

Answer (score 0):

I think that it is the problem of using AppPath.
Thats the path WWWroot. It is for create websites.
so you may don't have correct access permissions.

You can try some another path that you have correct access permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely (assuming missning asp.net tag) your code is running in ASP.Net application. Depending on chosen security model account the code runs under is either browser user's or special "anonymous" account. Both of accounts likley will not have write/create folder permissions in "inetpub\wwwroot" folder.

If you really want to let this access 
- figure out what user code runs under (i.e. check Environment.UserName at the moment of exception)
- if you are ok to give this user permissiosn - navigte local explorer to folder you want to create files/folders in and adjust permissions on "security" tab of folder properties.

In general writing files to semi-random locations (especially system controller ones like windows/program files/inetpub) is not a good idea. Make sure you understand security implications of your actions...

Note: make sure to construct paths correcly. `Path.Combine` is better way to do so over string concateneation and using long list of random slash/backslash characters.